# Correct usage of words about numbers and decimal places

Tags: numbers

I was told by a friend that they were taught to write numbers in this fashion: (1 ten thousanths, 1 thousandths, 1 hundreths, 1 tenths, 1 tens, 1 hundreds).

I was wondering why they would be taught in such a matter, and if this is actually gramatically correct.

Comment: If what is grammatically correct? Using the plural of the number word even when it's preceded by "1"? I can't imagine anyone saying "one ten," let alone "one tens," so you'll need to explain the context a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

0.0001 is one ten thousandth as in "a micron is one ten thousandth of a centimeter."

0.001 is one thousandth, as in "a micron is one thousandth of a millimeter."

0.01 is one hundredth, as in "a penny is one hundredth of a dollar"

0.1 is one tenth, as in "I walked one tenth of mile"

In all the examples above, you can say *a* instead of *one*.  "A micron is a ten thousandth of a centimeter."

10 is ten, as in "I owe you ten dollars"
'
100 is one hundred as in "I owe you one hundred dollars"  Also can say "I owe you a hundred dollars".

Note that I wrote out "one".  Writing "1 tenth" looks very odd.

Then there is the question of the hyphen.  My preference is ten-thousandth, one-thousandth, one-hundredth, one-tenth, but I don't think it matters whether you use the hyphen or not, unless you have a style guide (or a teacher) which insists that you conform.